# Is a user's Active Directory active using Delphi?

Tags: active-directory, delphi-2007

Last month a worker was fired.  HR set their AD account to inactive. The auditors discovered that such a user would still have access to the principle company program suite since we have our own access/authentication independent of AD.

My client has asked that when the user logs onto our program we add "has active AD account" to our authentication.

I have scoured SO and have found many solutions but none do the trick.

```
unit LDAPMain;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.StdCtrls, uADSI;

type
  TfrmElDapo = class(TForm)
    btnGetUser: TButton;
    edtDomain: TEdit;
    edtUser: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    edtGroup: TEdit;
    Label3: TLabel;
    procedure btnGetUserClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Memo1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
   ADSI: TADSI;
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  sdomain : string;
  sUID, sUserName, sDescription, sGroup : string;
  UserInfo :  uADSI.TADSIUserInfo;
  bDisabled:boolean;
 bLockedOut:boolean;
  end;

var
  frmElDapo: TfrmElDapo;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TfrmElDapo.btnGetUserClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
sdomain     := edtDomain.Text;
susername   := edtUser.Text;
sGroup      := edtGroup.Text;
  adsi.GetUser(domain, username, UserInfo);
  with UserInfo do
  begin
  sUID          :=   UID;
  sUserName     :=   UserName;
  sDescription  :=   Description;
  bDisabled     :=   Disabled;
  bLockedOut    :=   LockedOut;
  end;
  memo1.Lines.Add('UID: '+sUID);
  memo1.Lines.Add('UserName: '+sUserName);
  memo1.Lines.Add('Description: '+sDescription);
  memo1.Lines.Add('Disabled: '+BoolToStr(bDisabled));
  memo1.Lines.Add('LockedOut: '+BoolToStr(bLockedOut));
end;

procedure TfrmElDapo.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ADSI := TADSI.Create(self);
end;

procedure TfrmElDapo.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FreeAndNil(ADSI);
end;

procedure TfrmElDapo.Memo1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Clear;
end;

end.
```

In running the above, it pulls back the User name correctly but always shows the AD account as active, though they have been inactive for years!!! My client seems to think that that anomaly is due  to the fact that 
nsLookup DomainName returns over 50 servers and the search is returning the first one. I don't know how this works or whether his explanation is true.

I don't pretend to be a AD guru and have only dabbled in it a couple of time.

I am using ADSI at this point though I have tried ADO query.
Simply put, all I want is to put in a user's AD login and know whether he/she is active. What is the best/minimal code to accomplish this?

Comment: I have no idea of Delphi, but what you intend to do is a simple one-liner in powershell, or other language codes! You simply check whether the user-account is enabled OR not; and further if the user-account has expired (if you've implemented the same). Also, there might be a problem if your all domain controllers are not syncing properly; if that be the case, then your organisation would be in a deep trouble!!!

Comment: Your "with" block is assigning values in the UserInfo record back to the same UserInfo record. You are only going to see the default values for Disabled and Locked out in your memo.

Comment: @MarkElder  I saw this this morning and was coming in to make the changes when I saw your comment.  It all works now so I am accrediting you with the correct answer.